# Drupal joining multiple views in master view

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have multiple views I want to join into the one master view.

- View A: List of pages of content type A
- View B: List of pages of    content type B

I need to join Views A and B into Vew C, which will be the master view accessible via menu.

So far, I have found a module called "Views Field View", which works, but for me only for 50%.

For demonstration, I will add an image, which I will refer to:
[image]

The problem is, I cannot call the views A and B into main content - into FIELDS (Red on image).

For some reason, Anything with GLOBAL category will not get displayed.
Sadly, even "Custom text" and "Show" or "Views_field_view" are part of the GLOBAL category.

[image]

The only way how it is working now, is adding it as a HEADER (Blue on first image - HLAVIČKA).
So far so good.

[image]

But I need also add headers.
Bad thing is, that the inner views are shown without their headers. But in HEADER category on configuration of the view, there is no possibility of adding Global:Custom text, so I cannot add the headers manualy in master view C too...

So, any ideas, how to have

```
View C{
Header A 
View A
Header B
View B
}
```

Or

```
View C{
View A{header, content}
View B{header, content}
}
```

?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried to create a custom call who calls view_embed_view for each view ?

Comment: I think you can create a new view and add filter (Content type A and B) in it